# Add a new SharePoint Security group to all existing lists and libraries with unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, permissions, libraries, unique

In SharePoint 2010, I have a site collection with several subsites and hundreds of document libraries in sub sites. All these libraries have unique permissions. I have created 4 new SharePoint Groups in parent site collection. I want these security groups to be added into unique permissions of libraries of subsites. Is it possible through powershell or any other OOB technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following PowerShell script to add groups to list/library permissions. Iterate lists and libraries in the site and execute the function.

```
function Add-SPPermissionToListGroup
{
    param ($Url, $ListName, $GroupName, $PermissionLevel)
    $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url
    $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)
    if ($list -ne $null)
    {
        # Ensure that the permissions are not being inherited.
        if ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
        {
            if ($web.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
            {
                $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
                $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
                $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
                $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);
                $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
                $list.Update();
                Write-Host "Successfully added $PermissionLevel permission to $GroupName group in $ListName list. " -foregroundcolor Green
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Group $GroupName does not exist." -foregroundcolor Red
            }
        }      

    }
    $web.Dispose()
    }
```

Refer to: [Using powershell to work with SharePoint groups](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/02/using-powershell-to-work-with.html)